# Error in Spring integration - not processing further messages

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have the following configuration

```
<int:chain input-channel="requestsChannel">
    <int:splitter ref="aBean" method="aMethod" />
    <!-- routing to the appropriate processing channels -->
    <int:recipient-list-router default-output-channel="feedRequestChannel">
        <int:recipient channel="whateverRequestChannel" selector-expression="payload.source == 'whatever'"/>
    </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="feedRequestChannel" reply-channel="feedResponseChannel"
    url="{source}"
    http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="source" expression="payload.getSource()" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Now I get the error

```
   org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [{source}]
at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:398)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:167)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:199)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:51)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:273)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:268)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:576)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:532)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:504)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:449)
at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
... 57 more
```

which is not a problem. The `aMethod` returns a collection of two objects, one going through `feedRequestChannel` and second through `whateverRequestChannel`. But when I get the above error the second object is not processed anymore.

Is there any config so that I can ignore errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `<splitter>` produces several messages to send, it would be good, if its `output-channel` will some `thread-shift` (`executor`, `queue` etc.).

Having that the error for the first message won't impact the second one.

From other side, if you need sigle thread (one by one sending/processing), you can play a bit with `<request-handler-advice-chain>` for each of `<outbound-gateway>` to strangle error using `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with `trapException = true`